# Picture Quality on product page

Tags: magento2

I've managed to get a 100% picture quality on the fotorama slider when opening the picture, but on the product page the pictures are still compressed, getting good quality when clicking (opening) on them. I've changed the AbstractAdapter - set to 100% -, the Gd2.php set to quality=0 (no compression) and also the image.php got changed to $quality = 0 ;.

What can I do to get a full quality on the product page. It is very important to have a good picture quality to sell our services ...

Thank you in advance for some help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$image->quality(100)
```

In you **resize function** like this

```
Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(200, 230)->setQuality(100);
```

Hope this will help !!